# featured image background

Tags: post-thumbnails

trying to create a shortcode in funtions.php to show a featured post..

Everything I have works fine except I can't get the background-image to show the post's featured image...

echo $featured_post_url displays the correct address, but I just can't get it to show as the div's background image...

maybe ive been staring at the computer screen too long... can anybody tell me what i'm missing here?

```
    function propertunity_featured_post() {
      $featured_post_id = 2860;
      $featured_post = get_post($featured_post_id);
      $featured_post_url = get_permalink($featured_post_id);

      $featured_post_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url( 
      get_post_thumbnail_id($featured_post_id, 'thumbnail') );

      echo "

        <div class='card'>

          <div class='card-header' style='background-color: #f8f8fc; overflow: hidden;'>

            <a href='" . $featured_post_url . "'>

              <div class='card__image' style='background-image: url(' " . $featured_post_image_url . " ');'></div>       

            </a>

          </div>

       </div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can try `wp_get_attachment_image_src` this for getting Feature Image
>   URL. Here is the Full code.

```
<?php
function propertunity_featured_post() {
      $featured_post_id = 2860;
      $featured_post = get_post($featured_post_id);
      $featured_post_url = get_permalink($featured_post_id);
      $featured_post_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($featured_post_id, 'thumbnail') );
      echo "<div class='card'>
          <div class='card-header' style='background-color: #f8f8fc; overflow: hidden;'>
            <a href='" . $featured_post_url . "'>
              <div class='card__image' style='background-image: url(' " . $featured_post_image_url[0] . " ');'></div>       
            </a>
          </div>
       </div>";
}
?>
```